# ACE editor auto-completion duplicating prefix

Tags: ace-editor

I'm trying to add auto-completions for mermaid diagrams to my editor:

````js
    const mermaids = Object.entries({
        "mermaid graph": `graph LR\n    x --> y`,
    }).map(([name, autocompletion]) => ({
        caption: name,
        meta: name,
        value: "``mermaid\n" + autocompletion + "\n```"
    }));

    aceeditor.setOptions({
        enableBasicAutocompletion: [{
            getCompletions: (editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) => {
                callback(null, [
                    ...mermaids
                ])
            }
        }],
        enableSnippets: false,
        enableLiveAutocompletion: true
    });
````

In the resulting editor, if the user types "graph" or "mermaid" and hits enter to auto-complete, it works as expected. (With the exception of less-than desirable cursor position after the completion.) If the user types "```" and hits enter, the autocompletion occurs *after* the originally typed "```". E.g.,

```````
``````mermaid
graph LR
    x --> y
\```                  <-- just escaped here for SO's sake
```````

Is there an efficient way to correct this? If not, what event can I use to determine when an auto-completion has actually occurred and search for duplicate markers?

Is there a better way to do this in general?

Answer (score 0):

I think the broader issue here is that your completion item more closely resembles a snippet. Using snippets would also give you better control over where the cursor goes after insertion.

Answering your second question, [Autocomplete.insertMatch](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/23208f2f19020d1f69b90bc3b02460bda8422072/src/autocomplete.js#L139) is the function responsible for inserting the chosen completion item. You could hook it, or perhaps use the mysteriously undocumented `.completer` field on the completion items? It's been there for [9 years now](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/commit/f6f475747b09a6fd865e8d83941079739b3828af), perhaps it is not an accident.

````js
const FakeCompleter = {
    insertMatch: (editor, data) => {
        // stolen from default insertMatch, needed to erase text that triggered our completion:
        if (editor.completer.completions.filterText) {
            var ranges = editor.selection.getAllRanges()
            for (var i = 0, range; range = ranges[i]; i++) {
                range.start.column -= editor.completer.completions.filterText.length
                editor.session.remove(range)
            }
        }
        
        // if there are ` symbols immediately before cursor, omit those from completion:
        let text = (data.value || data)
        const lead = editor.selection.lead
        const prefix = editor.session.getLine(lead.row).substring(0, lead.column)
        const mt = /.*?(`{1,3})$/.exec(prefix)
        if (mt && text.startsWith(mt[1])) text = text.substring(mt[1].length)
        
        // and finally call the regular insertion:
        editor.execCommand("insertstring", text)
    }
}
const mermaids = Object.entries({
    "mermaid graph": `graph LR\n    x --> y`,
}).map(([name, autocompletion]) => ({
    caption: name,
    meta: name,
    value: "``mermaid\n" + autocompletion + "\n```",
    completer: FakeCompleter
}));
````